Chunks work fine, but knit fails as object are not found
Hope you can help me fix the following error. I created an dataframe called final_dataset and I want to perform a couple of mixed model analysis on this dataframe. So I wrote some chunks for this
library(lme4)
library(naniar)
library(tidyverse)

model <- final_dataset |> filter(marker_id == "crp" & pbd < 15)

fm1 <- lmer(result ~ study * pbd + (1|study_nr), model)
summary(fm1)

model$pred <- predict(fm1, re.form = ~0)
ggplot(model, aes(pbd, result))+
  geom_line(aes(group = study_nr))+
  geom_point(aes(y = pred, col = study), size = 2)+
  labs(x =  "pbd", y = "result", col = "Study")

This chunks works fine, so I added more chunks for different markers for the analysis
model <- final_dataset |> filter(marker_id == "leuco" & pbd < 15)

fm1 <- lmer(result ~ study * pbd + (1|study_nr), model)
summary(fm1)

model$pred <- predict(fm1, re.form = ~0)
ggplot(model, aes(pbd, result))+
  geom_line(aes(group = study_nr))+
  geom_point(aes(y = pred, col = study), size = 2)+
  labs(x =  "pbd", y = "result", col = "Study")

This chunks also works. No I want to knit the markdown to create a HTML document. My YAML header looks like this..
title: "LMER"
author: "M Vlig"
date: "r Sys.Date()"
output: html_document
However, the knit fails with the following error.
Quitting from lines  at lines 13-27 [unnamed-chunk-1] (LMER.Rmd)
Error:
! object 'final_dataset' not found
Backtrace:

dplyr::filter(final_dataset, marker_id == "crp" & pbd < 15)

Execution halted.
It says that the object "final_dataset" can't be found, but it is available... As the seperate chnuks will work... How can I fix this. Here is a screenshot..

I already tried to restart R and I created a new RMD file, but the error remains..
I hope someone has the answer for me.
Thanks
M

You don't seem to define final_dataset in the RMD document itself. When you knit a file, it runs in separate process. it does not use values in the current global environment. A RMD document must be self sufficient and all the code for the data needs to be in there.

I agree with MrFlick's comment. Given your screenshot of the code chunk provided above, the sweet spot to include your definition of final_dataset would be in line 16.

Thanks, didn't know that was required. Now it works.
